how to delete all start up bash scripts
I downloaded a few plugins and deleted them but I do not think I deleted them properly therefore my terminal now has some weird features I would like to get rid of.
I ran

echo exit | strace bash -li |& grep '^open'

to see what scripts are running however I do not know how to delete all the non default ones
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash.bashrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/init.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash_completion.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash_completion.d/apport_completion", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/gawk.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/gnome-session_gnomerc.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/im-config_wayland.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/X11/Xsession.d/70im-config_launch", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.bash_profile", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.bash_login", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.profile", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.bashrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/oh-my-bash.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.osh-update", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/utils.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/custom/lib/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/custom/lib/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/base.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/bourne-shell.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/init.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash_completion.d/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash_completion.d/apport_completion", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/directories.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/functions.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/git.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/omb-prompt-colors.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/omb-deprecate.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/omb-prompt-base.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/omb-util.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/grep.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/history.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.inputrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/inputrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/misc.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/mo.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/nvm.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/omb-completion.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/readlink.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/shopt.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/spectrum.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/spinner.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/lib/theme-and-appearance.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/plugins/git/git.plugin.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/plugins/bashmarks/bashmarks.plugin.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/aliases/general.aliases.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/completions/git.completion.bash", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/doc/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/completions/composer.completion.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/completions/ssh.completion.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/custom/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/custom/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/custom/example.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/themes/rr/rr.theme.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.nvm/nvm.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.nvm/bash_completion", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.config/envman/load.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.config/envman/function.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.config/envman/alias.env", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.cargo/env", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.bash_history", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ingar/.bash_logout", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash.bash_logout", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)



You've provided few specifics; as there are many scripts which will run at various times (eg. some when you open terminal; others on boot & some on first login), with some impacted by the terminal you actually use. We currently don't know what you're running, so can't suggest much; I'd expect whomever installed it would have a better idea of what was installed & on what system they were installed.  I'd probably look first at what exists at  ls ~/.bash* -ltrha  as even the metadata (time/date of change) maybe a clue, even if only some places to look.

Looking at the sequence, and considering that it would make very much sense, it looks as if the oh-my-bash thing at /home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/oh-my-bash.sh is sourcing most of the stuff. Removing source /home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/oh-my-bash.sh, . /home/ingar/.oh-my-bash/oh-my-bash.sh or whatever command is sourcing that file from (most likely) ~/.bashrc should get rid of most "third-party" stuff. Then with a clean output rinse and repeat with other non-standard files if some stuff is left.

Same probably goes for /home/ingar/.config/envman/load.sh and /home/ingar/.cargo/env. Much like oh-my-bash, it's not guaranteed they'll be sourced by ~/.bashrc, but I'd check there first.

oh ok thank you so do i just see what is actually in the .bashrc file to know what runs on startup?

In this case, most likely everything will be in either ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile. This is not always the case though, the chain of files a shell sources depends on many factors (e.g. login vs non-login shell) and is non-deterministic (as it depends on the sourced files themselves), and even in the simplest cases there are also global configuration files being sourced. See here for an outline of the "standard" sourcing mechanism (which in practice could be affected by distribution-specific modifications).

But most of the time yes, user-specific modifications will be done by editing ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile, so those are usually the first files to look at
